# pymssql, fetchall for table with many colnames couse error: (20047, b'DB-Lib error message 20047, severity 9:\nDBPROCESS is dead or not enabled\n')

Tags: sql-server, pymssql, fetchall

I call pymssql, fetchall for table "CDN.Kontrahenci", and where I enter many columns names, as:

```py
"Knt_KntId,Knt_Kod,Knt_Nazwa1,Knt_Nazwa2,Knt_Nazwa3,Knt_Kraj,Knt_Wojewodztwo,Knt_Ulica,Knt_NrDomu,Knt_NrLokalu,Knt_Miasto,Knt_KodPocztowy,Knt_Poczta,Knt_NipE,Knt_Nip,Knt_Regon,Knt_Pesel,Knt_Telefon1,Knt_Telefon2,Knt_Fax,Knt_Email,Knt_URL,Knt_OsKraj,Knt_Opis,Knt_OpeZalID,Knt_OpeModID,Knt_TS_Zal,Knt_TS_Mod"
```

I have received error:

> (20047, b'DB-Lib error message 20047, severity 9:
> DBPROCESS is dead or not enabled
> ')

When I call less amount of columns names, like:

```py
"Knt_KntId,Knt_Kod,Knt_Nazwa1,Knt_Nazwa2,Knt_Nazwa3"
```

everything is ok.

When I call this table for all column names, like:

```py
sql = "SELECT * FROM CDN.Kontrahenci"
```

I've received above error as well.
Why is this error. Anyone has an idea?

I was not be able find solution for this problem in the internet and I expected advice about listed error.

Comment: What happens when you run this command from a client like SSMS

Comment: Or try pyodbc instead.

Comment: No error. I have ST03\MSSQL2022 Express 64bit, and I call mssql from Linux MInt 21.1 with Python v.3.10.12 and pymssql v.2.2.11

Comment: I don't know how to run pyodbc on Linux Mint :-( I have tried but I can't establish connection.